# Linker error calling C function from C++ despite using EXTERN "C"

Tags: c++, c, visual-studio-2008, linker-errors

I am using this library
http://rtmpdump.mplayerhq.hu/librtmp.3.html which is written in C.
It already uses extern "C" on all of its definitions. But still when I call a function from my [main.cpp] file,, compiler shows these errors:

```
[1>main.obj : error LNK2028: unresolved token (0A00000F) "extern "C" struct RTMP * 
 __cdecl RTMP_Alloc(void)" (?RTMP_Alloc@@$$J0YAPAURTMP@@XZ) referenced in function "int 
 __cdecl main(void)" (?main@@$$HYAHXZ)]

[1>main.obj : error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol "extern "C" struct RTMP * 
 __cdecl RTMP_Alloc(void)" (?RTMP_Alloc@@$$J0YAPAURTMP@@XZ) referenced in function "int 
 __cdecl main(void)" (?main@@$$HYAHXZ)]
```

I am using Visual Studio 2008. And there is no compilation error.
What am I missing?

Comment: what is the compile line just previous to this error?  (IOW, I'm pretty sure you aren't including the library/object file that includes this function)

Comment: There is no compilation error because it's the linker that complains. Do you actually link against the library?

Comment: Did you properly tell your compiler to link with the librtmp library ? It must be something like -lrtmp on the compiler command line invocation.

Comment: @KevinDTimm: I have include the .h file, and calling that function is only line in my main.

Comment: If everything is as you've told us then the problem is that you haven't got your build settings correct. Most likely you haven't told the linker to link with the library.

Comment: @john: I have added library directory to "additional library directories".Do I need to do anything else?

Comment: You need to add the library file name itself (to a different place, linker/inputs I think)

Comment: adding my .h file to additiinal dependencies give this error:[fatal error LNK1107: invalid or corrupt file: cannot read at 0x25BB] ,, may be because it is for binding .lib files only

Comment: add the library name to the additional dependencies, not the .h file name

Comment: there are no dll files, I have .h and .c files only. I need to include them in my code. I have #included them and have written extern c in their definitions. What else do I need to do?

Comment: @Lohrun: what is -lrtmp? ,, I searched google, shows nothing

Comment: @Prince -lrtmp is the usual command line argument to link a library with an executable.

If you do not have any .dll file for your library you must include the .h and .c file into your project, compile them, so that the linker can find the symbol defined in the .h.

Comment: The error message is interesting.  I wonder if the `extern "C"` is applying to the struct only and not the function name.  Can you try forcing it with a local declaration right above the main where it is being called; like this: `extern "C" { struct RTMP *RTMP_Alloc(); }`

Comment: Looking at the sources for version 2.3 of this code, it looks right.  Is there no second declaration of `RTMP_Alloc` that might be confusing matters?  Preprocessing the code and looking at the output would help.  Then, it would be possible to search for `RTMP_Alloc` and find where it's declared, then check if that's within an `extern "C"` block.

Comment: @ash Why did you delete your answer? Perhaps OP is using an older version of the headers. Judging by the error message, your conclusion seems to be the most reasonable.

Comment: Hmm, maybe.  I'll put it back.  After reading the code, I thought it was unlikely to be the answer.

Answer (score 2):

Here's a scenario that fits the symptoms.  Two source files and a header.

**first.c**

```
#include "first.h"

struct RTMP     *RTMP_Alloc()
{
        return  (struct RTMP *) 0;
}
```

**second.cpp**

```
#include "first.h"

int main (int argc, char **argv)
{
        RTMP *result;

        result = RTMP_Alloc();

        return  0;
}
```

**first.h**

```
#ifdef __cplusplus
extern "C"
#endif
struct RTMP
{
        int val1;
        int val2;
} ;

struct RTMP     *RTMP_Alloc();
```

Notice that the `extern "C"` only applies to the struct definition.  To correct it, either it needs to be inserted before the `RTMP_Alloc` definition, or even easier for large blocks, put inside an `extern "C" { ... }` construct (notice the addition of the curly braces).

Comment: Interestingly,, even that has been taken care off.

Comment: may be I am confusing what to mention in "Include Directories" , "Library Directories" ,,"External Dependencies" , "Header files" etc.
I am very new to Visual Studio and I am working on it now, and I would definitely share my findings.